# Distributed runners cache Gitlab Runner Path = path/to/prefix

Tags: caching, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, runner

reading the documentation about [distributed runners cache](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/autoscale.html#distributed-runners-caching) I was wondering what the variable "**Path**" in the config.toml does.

```
 [runners.cache]
    Type = "s3"
    **Path = "path/to/prefix"**
    Shared = false
```

Does this just change the S3 url http(s)://ServerAddress/BucketName/**Path**/runner/runner-id/project/id/cache-key ?

If so what consequences can I expect when I change/add the path variable? When and how would you use it?

Answer (score 0):

The `Path` from the config ends up like this when connecting to S3 `http(s)://<ServerAddress>/<BucketName>/<Path>/runner/<runner-id>/project/<id>/<cache-key>` where `<Path>` is what you entered in the config. You can see this in the docs page you linked in your question right under the config example with the black background.